# Azure deployed wordpress site permission to view error

Tags: wordpress, azure

We have an azure hosted site at www.roburir.com (built in asp)

I am wanting to add a wordpress site at the url www.roburir.com/articles.

Have created and successfully deployed a wordpress site at:

http://robur-articles.azurewebsites.net

Have then written a rewrite code in the web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>


    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="SEOAzureRewrite" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^robur-articles.azurewebsites.net$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.roburir.com/articles{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This redirect works, however I am getting a 404 error and the message:

You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

Have tried moving the webconfig to different folders but still no joy.

Any help would be much appreciated cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a virtual directory "articles" on your www.roburir.com site  then deploy your WordPress site to it.

You can follow this article for a full description of the method:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2014/04/19/microsoft-azure-web-sites-deploying-wordpress-to-a-virtual-directory-within-the-azure-web-site/

Comment: @DavidOak will you be kind enough to mark this as the accepted answer since it worked for you. Thanks.